# VBA PowerPoint - How to select specific slides or by section and export to MP4?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

For example: export slide number 30 up to 80 (export to mp4).
some macro for that?
Or: export only one section.

I found a macro that exports slides by sections, but it is in png and when I switch to mp4 it doesn't work. (Rodrigo Moraes macro).

```
Sub Test_Export()                                                          
                                                                           
Dim sld As Slide
i = 1
                                                                
DesiredSection = SectionIndexOf("Test")
                                                                           
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
                                                                            
If sld.sectionIndex = DesiredSection Then
   ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Export filenamepng & "TEST" & i & ".png", "PNG"
End If
                                                                             
i = i + 1
                                                                          
Next
                                                                           
                                                                           
End Sub
                                                                      
Function SectionIndexOf(sSectionName As String) As Long
    Dim x As Long
    With ActivePresentation.SectionProperties
        For x = 1 To .Count
            If .Name(x) = sSectionName Then
                SectionIndexOf = x
            End If
        Next
    End With                                                                   
End Function
```

A user (Albert Floor) is able to export selected slides to PDF with this macro

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim myInput As String
Dim savePath As String\

'Name of Student
myInput = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("TextBox2").OLEFormat.Object.Text\

'Location of saved file
savePath = ActivePresentation.Path & "\" & myInput & " Antwoorden Virtueel Lab" & ".pdf"  \\\\

'Select path student took
If ActivePresentation.Slides(9).Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Text = "PRARDT" Then

'Change view
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit

'Prevents error 
ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate

'Select specific slides
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(9, 11, 15)).Select

'save selected slides as PDF
ActivePresentation.ExportAsFixedFormat Path:=savePath, FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, RangeType:=ppPrintSelection

MsgBox "file saved"

Else
MsgBox "wont work"

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't make a copy of the slideshow, delete the slides you don't want, and then record it with [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) or similar?

Comment: Can you give more explanation about what issue you're having and what you hope the macro could do?

Comment: Looks like you are new here. Please read this guide on how to ask a question that will get good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Beefster 
About deleting slides, I have many of them and with videos / images, so when I try to delete I have to wait a long time and often PowerPoint stops working and I have to close it.
I record with OBS, but I do massive work, this recording time throughout the day takes me a long time. For this reason I open several powerpoints in Sandboxie to export several videos at the same time.
I'm following it this way because PowerPoint can't use even 40% of my hardware constantly, I've already asked for help in Microsoft support and executed numerous tutorials, but it didn't work.

Comment: @HackSlash 
thanks for the indication, I will read

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I'm having trouble doing massive mp4 export. When trying to delete multiple slides it takes a long time and sometimes crashes because I have many slides with videos / images. I hope a macro will allow me to export specific slides to mp4 to work around all these problems. For example: export slide number 30 up to 80 (export to mp4).

Comment: 1. Rather than deleting the slides, hide them. In the left-hand list of slide thumbnails, right-click and choose Hide Slide. 2. If there are sets of slides that often appear together, use Slide Show>Custom Slide Show and make a subset of slides to display.

Comment: @JohnKorchok 
1- hide slides continues to export hidden slides. 2- also continues to export all slides.

Comment: That's because you've set RangeType to ppPrintSelection. Open File>Print, click on the Print All Slides dropdown, uncheck _Print Hidden Slides_, then run it again.

Comment: @JohnKorchok 
I tested it again and it worked, the loading bar seems to take a long time, but it shows as if it were exporting even the hidden slides, it's like a bug. Besides, I didn't need to set the range type.
However, it exports only the non-hidden and does not need to wait for the loading bar to reach 100%. In other words it works perfectly, although using control + z still gives me trouble undoing the hide like crash / freezing.
For this reason I would like to use a macro to export only selected slides in mp4 or perhaps by section. But thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've never exported a powerpoint presentation to mp4 but in powerpoint 2013, the version I have, you seem to be able to create an mp4 when you *Save As*.

Save as honours hidden slides. So some simple code to hide slides then save as works, here is some sample code. In this example I hide all slides after the fifth.

```vba
Public Sub Savetomp4()
    Dim mySlides As slides
    Set mySlides = ActivePresentation.slides
    Dim aSlide As Slide
    
    ' Hide some slides
    For i = 0 To mySlides.Count - 1
       If i > 5 Then
           Set aSlide = mySlides.Item(i)
           aSlide.SlideShowTransition.Hidden = msoTrue
       End If
    Next i
    
    ' Save as mp4
    ActivePresentation.SaveAs "c:\temp\test.mp4", ppSaveAsMP4
    Debug.Print "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: It continues to save hidden slides: /

Comment: I tested it again and it works, the loading bar seems to take a long time, the export finishes before reaching 100%, as a visual bug. It works perfectly, although it has problems undoing the hiding of the slides, as they crash the PC. For this reason I need a macro that allows me to export only selected slides, or by section, so that I don't have to use control + z, avoiding crashing. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you tried adapting the code to un-hide the slides you had hidden? So you don't need to interact with any of the user interface?